# Proof that $\left(X^A\right)^B$ is homeomorphic to $X^{A\times B}$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$

Tags: general-topology, functions

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint index sets. For arbitrary index set $\Lambda $, give the set $X^\Lambda$ the product topology, which means $X^\Lambda$ is exactly the product space $\Pi_{\lambda\in \Lambda} X_\lambda$, where $X_\lambda=X$ for all $\lambda\in \Lambda$. I want to prove that $X^{A\times B}$ is homeomorphic to $\left( X^A\right)^B$.

**My attempt :** Put
$$ F:X^{A\times B}\to \left( X^A\right)^B,\left (   F\left ( f \right )  \left ( b \right )  \right )   \left ( a \right ) =f\left ( a,b \right ), $$
then it is easy to verify that $F$ is a bijection. Can we prove that $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuous? Can you please help me?

Comment: You don't even need $A,B$ to be disjoint for this to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint is irrelevant (if it helps, given sets $A$ and $B$, one can find a set $B'$ with the cardinality of $B$ and disjoint from $A$ and all the same topologies will be produced).

A basis for the topology of $Y^S$ where $Y$ is a topological space and $S$ is an index set is given by products $\Pi_{s \in S} U_S$ where each $U_S$ is open and $U_s = Y$ for all but finitely many $s \in S$. So we need to check what your $F$ does to these subsets.

Consider a set of the form $\Pi_{(a,b) \in A \times B} U_{(a,b)}$ where $U_{(a,b)} \subset X$. You should convince yourself that
\begin{equation*}
F\left(\Pi_{(a,b) \in A \times B} U_{(a,b)} \right) = \Pi_{b \in B} \Pi_{a \in A} U_{(a,b)}. 
\end{equation*}
Consider such a subset whereby $U_{(a,b)} \subset X$ is open for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$ and $U_{(a,b)} = X$ for all but finitely many $(a,b) \in A \times B$. Note if a subset $S$ of $A \times B$ is finite, so is the set $S_{(A,b)} = \{ a \in A : (a,b) \in S \}$ for fixed $b \in B$ and the set $S_B = \{b \in B : (a,b) \in S \exists a \in A \}$. This respectively implies that for each $a \in A$, $\Pi_{b \in B} U_{(a,b)}$ is open in $X^A$ and $\Pi_{a \in B} U_{(a,b)} = X^A$ for all but finitely many $b \in B$. Thus, this image is open. So, $F$ is an open map.

Now for continuity of $F$. Consider a set of the form $\Pi_{b \in B}U_b$ where $U_b$ is open in $X^A$ for each $b \in B$ and $U_b = X^A$ for all but finitely many $b \in B$. Let $f \in \Pi_{b \in B}U_b$. Then, for each $b$, $f(b) \in U_b$ so that there exists a neighbourhood of $f(b)$ of the form $\Pi_{a \in A} (U_b)_a$ where $(U_b)_a$ is open in $X$ for all $a \in A$ and $(U_b)_a = X$ for all but finitely many $a \in A$. Set $U_{(a,b)} = (U_b)_A$ for $(a,b) \in A \times B$. If $S \subset A \times B$ and we know that $S_{(A,b)} = \{a \in A : (a,b) \in S\}$ for all fixed $b \in B$ is finite and also that $S_B = \{b \in B : (a,b) \in S \exists a \in A\}$ is finite, then $S$ is finite. This shows that $\Pi_{(a,b) \in A \times B} U_{(a,b)}$ is open in $X^{A \times B}$ and moreover, using our previous (displayed) equation
\begin{equation*}
F(\Pi_{(a,b) \in A \times B} U_{(a,b)}) \subset \Pi_{b \in B}U_b.
\end{equation*}
This completes continuity of $F$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly know that the product topology on $P =\prod_{c \in C} Z_c$ has the following universal property:

- A function $G : W \to P$ on a topological space $W$ is continuous iff all $p_c \circ G : W \to Z_c$ are continuous, where the $p_c : P \to Z_c$ are the projections (which are known to be continuous).

Now let $p^{A \times B}_{(a,b)} : X^{A \times B} \to X$, $p^A_a : X^A \to X$ and $p^B_b : (X^A)^B \to X^A$ denote the projections onto the factors indicated by the respective indices.

1. To prove that $F$ is continuous it suffices to show that all $p^B_b \circ F : X^{A \times B} \to X^A$ are continuous. To show this, it suffices to verify that all $p^A_a \circ p^B_b \circ F : X^{A \times B} \to X$ are continuous. But $p^A_a \circ p^B_b \circ F = p^{A \times B}_{(a,b)}$ and we are done.
2. To prove that $F^{-1}$ is continuous it suffices to show that all $p^{A \times B}_{(a,b)} \circ F^{-1} :  (X^A)^B \to X$ are continuous. But $p^{A \times B}_{(a,b)} \circ F^{-1} = p^A_a \circ p^B_b$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your bijection $F$ is in fact a homeomorphism. This is a special case of the *exponential law*. One usually endows functions spaces $U^V$ with the compact-open topology. For spaces $X,Y,Z$ we have a well-defined function
$$F : X^{Y \times Z} \to (X^Y)^Z, F(f)(z,y) = f(y,z) .$$
The exponential law says that

1. $F$ is a bijection provided $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff.
2. $F$ is a homeomorphism if additionally $Z$ is Hausdorff.

If $V$ is discrete, then the compact-open topology on $U^V$ agrees with the product topology $\prod_{v \in V} U_v$, where all $U_v = U$. Giving $A, B$ the discrete topology, also $A \times B$ has the discrete topology and your result follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an immediate consequence of the Yoneda Lemma. For any space $Y$, we have the following isomorphisms, natural in $Y$:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Hom(Y, X^{A \times B}) 
&\cong Hom(Y, X)^{A \times B}\\
&\cong (Hom(Y, X)^A)^B \\
&\cong Hom(Y, X^A)^B \\
&\cong Hom(Y, (X^A))^B
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

As a reminder, in the case of the category of topological spaces, $Hom(K, M)$ is the set of continuous functions $K \to M$, not the set of homeomorphisms.

Therefore, by the Yoneda lemma, there is an isomorphism - that is, a homeomorphism - $X^{A \times B} \cong (X^A)^B$. Note that the proof applies in any category where $A$-ary and $B$-ary products exist. It is a special case of limits distributing over limits.